# Preprocessing text manually (iOS Arabic Fonts problem)

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, arabic

I have problem using arabic font for iOS.
All fonts have the same render, and I am trying to test the workaround described here: 
[Custom Arabic font in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691567/custom-arabic-font-in-ios/4361653#4361653)

The problem is that I don't know how to use it, I added ArabicShaping h and cpp files
The code compiles but I don't know what to do next.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, did you managed to fix the problem? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: @Mustafa no, I didn't. Finally I used the standard font.

Comment: I filed a bug at bugreport.apple.com, i suggest that you do the same. The more bug reports they'll get, the more attention this issue will get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i have created new class in objective c that do just this, it allow you to use custom fonts for arabic text in ios, check github
https://github.com/Accorpa/Arabic-Converter-From-and-To-Arabic-Presentation-Forms-B

Comment: Nice, This works for some fonts, I tried it with two fonts, and one work while the second does not. Also there is a character that was not correctly displayed in my first test.

Comment: i realized that not all fonts are actually supported in mac, if u use finder to see the font, u will see that it on the left it shows only an icon with "T" on it, this means this font will not work in the solution i made, but if you see in finder the font is showing characters like "A B C .." or Arabic characters this means it will work, try and tell me if u solved this or not.

Comment: I tested with GeezaProBold font, Finder display arabic characters, but it does not work. You can find this font in https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Attf+GeezaProBold .   Also when I tested with the font KufiStandardGK , it works, but I notice that the character "ه" is not well displayed

Comment: Can someone list which fonts this works with? I tried with a few (unfortunately I didn't keep track of which) but all of them rendered with missing glyphs

Answer (score 1):

For complex font rendering, you'll need to use another library as iOS does not support it. One such library is available on github.

https://github.com/mta452/SheenFigure

It uses FreeType or CoreGraphics for glyph rendering. Currently it supports Arabic/Urdu fonts with complete substitution and positioning.

Comment: this code working fine and supporting almost all the custom fonts but when I tried to use this code in my project it never worked, can you please see and share some video tutorial how to use that?
Thanks.