# How to make "Andalus" Custom font not work in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ipad

"Andalus" custom font not work in `UITableViewCell`. Steps followed:

- Add font file name "Andalus.ttf" to "Fonts provided by application" key in app-info.plist
- Get font name using `NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont familyNames]);` // it return "Andalus"
- Set font name using:   `cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Andalus" size:10];`

  ```
  cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Andalus" size:10];
  ```

in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but a word like 'حمل' not appear as in a textedit with the same font

I get data using `UTF8` from `sqlite`

thank you for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Andalus have more than one variant, e.g. Andalus Strong and Andalus Sharp? If that is the case you have to specify the name of the variant you wish to use.

Check the array returned by `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Andalus"]`

Comment: thank you for reply. but it doesn't. and [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Andalus"] just return Andalus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691567/custom-arabic-font-in-ios

This is my question with misunderstanding answer. can every one make answer more clear and how to integrate with ios app.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the updated list of font can be used:

http://iosfonts.com/

Also, there is an app you can see how the fonts look like:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/fonts/id285217489?mt=8