# What is the easiest way to change a custom embeded font of UINavigationBar's title

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I have over 20 `UINavigationBars` need to change the font of their titles, and based on all the tutorials I saw, there is one way to do this which is change the bar `UILabel`, so I used below code:

```
+ (void) applyFontForUINavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)navItem withTitle:(NSString *) title{
    UILabel *navLabel = [Util generateNabBarLabel withText:title];
    [navLabel setFontName:FONT_NAME_BOLD];
    navItem.titleView = navLabel;
}
```

It works fine, but I don't want to add this odd line in all my `ViewControllerss`' `viewDidLoad`, is there a legal way to do this even with subclassing ?

**EDIT**:
I am using custom font from a ttf file same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029660/use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-app?lq=1).

and after applying apperance I got this:

[image]

Note that `setFont` doesn't work for Arabic Custome font according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691567/custom-arabic-font-in-ios) so am using below for UILabels:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myLabel.text attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : myLabel.font, NSLigatureAttributeName: @1}];
myLabel.attributedText =   attributedString;
```

And it works fine (for UILabel).

Answer (score 1):

try to use with UIAppearance feature to set the navigation bar tile font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the appearance delegate to change the font via the title text attributes:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME_BOLD size:17] }];
```

Comment: Doesn't' work, dude sorry for the late edit, please check it in my question.

Comment: It should work, you just need to get the font name right. What is the `setFontName:` method you're using in your code?

Comment: I am using this for UILabel and it works fine:     NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myLabel.text attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : myLabel.font, NSLigatureAttributeName: @1}];
    myLabel.attributedText =   attributedString;self.font,NSLigatureAttributeName: @1}];
    label.attributedText =   attributedString;

Comment: You should be able to add the font you create for the label currently into the text attributes dictionary.

Comment: It seems like a bug in iOS, so I am setting attributedText rather than font.

Answer (score 0):

1.If edit your project in code I have a idea by inheriting a super navigation controller which has changed the `navigation bar` tile `font size`.

2.If you edit your project in `storyboard`, you can search `.storyboard` in  your project, in `storyboard` you can easy edit the `navigationbar` to change the `font`.

I takon a photo for you below:
[image: three steps to edit your navigationbar in storyboard]